# Broadcasting the high word in AVX2

Tags: x86, intel, simd, micro-optimization, avx2

The `vpbroadcastw` instruction introduced in AVX2 conveniently (?) broadcasts the low 16-bit WORD to all locations in a 32-byte `ymm` register.

Because I'm a contrarian, I'd like to instead broadcast the *high* word (bits 255:240) of an AVX2 register to all elements.

The best I could come up with was a lane-crossing shuffle, followed by a `pshufb` byte-wise shuffle, something like this:

```cpp
inline __m256i bcast_mse(__m256i v) {
    __m256i temp = _mm256_permute2x128_si256(v, v, 0x11);
    __m256i ctrl = _mm256_set_epi8(  // clang-format off
        15, 14, 15, 14, 15, 14, 15, 14,
        15, 14, 15, 14, 15, 14, 15, 14,
        15, 14, 15, 14, 15, 14, 15, 14,
        15, 14, 15, 14, 15, 14, 15, 14
    );  // clang-format on
    return _mm256_shuffle_epi8(temp, ctrl);
}
```

Is there anything better? Obviously I'd prefer a single-instruction, but assuming that's not going to happen, maybe something that involves the need for this 32-byte shuffle control.

Answer (score 4):

AVX512BW `vpermw` can do this on SKX and later.  2 uops on SKX, but down to 1 uop on later Intel.

---

With AVX2, you can broadcast in 2 steps with two immediate shuffles, no control vec:

- fill the high qword using in-lane [`vpshufhw ymm`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pshufhw)
  `_mm256_shufflehi_epi16(v, _MM_SHUFFLE(3,3,3,3))`
- broadcast that with `vpermq` immediate.
  `_mm256_permute4x64_epi64` or `_mm256_permutex_epi64(v2, _MM_SHUFFLE(3,3,3,3))`

I think it would take at least 2 non-shuffle instructions (like `vpsrld` / `vpblendw`) to set up for a `vpermd` (with a control vector) to broadcast the high dword.  But that doesn't help because `vpblendw` is p5-only even on SKL/SKX.

---

Also store/reload is an option if shuffle throughput is a bottleneck, e.g. `vextracti128` of the high half, then broadcast load from the high word of that.  (But broadcast loads narrower than a dword still need a shuffle uop).

Comment: Huh, good solution - clang's shuffle optimizer didn't find that one. Too bad `vpermq` is slow on Zen.

Comment: @BeeOnRope: oh, yeah if you do this a lot in-lane `vpshufb` plus `vperm2i128` should be better on Zen2.  But `vperm2i128` is even worse than `vpermq` on Zen1 for some reason.  (Agner found `vperm2f128` = 8 uops, didn't test `vperm2i128`)

Comment: What's weird about `vperm2i128` is that it seems like whatever the control immediate you could build a strictly faster version with some combination of `vextracti128`, `vinserti128` and some blend. I.e. the sum of the inverse throughput of all of those is less than a single `vperm2i128`, and in most cases you need only 1 or 2 of those. Maybe it's the zeroing feature of `vperm2i128` that kills it.